# Google Charts API - All series on a given axis must be of the same data type - when drawing

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to display some statistics via Google Charts API, but for some reason I'm getting this weird issue which I couldn't figure out for days.

I am getting this error:

> All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

This would be my code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
    rows = [];

// Add columns
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    for (var j in response[i]) {
        var column = response[i][j];
        rows.push([new Date(column.date), column.collection, Number(column.count)]);
    }
}

console.log(rows);
data.addRows(rows);

var options = {
  title: 'Chart display',
  hAxis: { title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: { color: '#333' } },
  vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById(chartId));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

When I `console.log` the `rows` variable, this is the output:

```
0: Array[3]
    0: Wed Nov 11 2015 16:07:36 GMT+0100 (CET)
    1: "views"
    2: 1
1: Array[3]
    0: Wed Nov 11 2015 16:07:36 GMT+0100 (CET)
    1: "completions"
    2: 1
```

And this seems completely alright! There is nothing wrong with any of the data types and yet I get that error.

I am unable to see the problem.

Comment: Strings and datetimes are both qualifiers for being put in the first column with Area Charts, but neither of them is supposed to go into the second column, only numbers. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#data-format

What are you trying to accomplish? 
I assume that you want to group it by date, so then I would go ahead and make columns for every "collection" you have, so your example would have 3 colums. Date, Views, Completions.

Comment: @HenrikAronsson I originally tried to do that, but I was unable to figure it out. I would appreciate help on this too. I'm confused as this is the first time I have ever worked with charts.

Comment: It all comes down to how you build your response. Either you format it as some custom array/object and populate your data manually, or you format it as googles JSON-format.
Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/1tyw89o7/1/

First example uses a custom one with populating each cell one by one, the other one uses googles requested format for JSON, find more info here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data looks like it's structured like this :

```
Date      Type          Count
Nov 10    category1     10
Nov 10    category2     13
Nov 11    category1     8
Nov 11    category2     5
```

It should be structured like this:

```
Date      Category1    Category2
Nov 10    10           13
Nov 11    8            5
```

Either alter your input source or restructure it using JavaScript.